# How do I use the mean-value theorem in this question?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function. Show that if $P = \{x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ is a partition of $[a,b]$ then
> $$L(P, f') = \sum_{j=1}^n m_j \Delta x_j \leq f(b) - f(a)$$
> where $m_j = \inf\{f'(t): t \in [x_{j-1}, x_j]\}$ and $\Delta x_j = x_j - x_{j-1}$ for each $1 \leq j \leq n$.
>
> *Hint:* Use the Mean-value theorem.

I realize the hint tells me to use the mean value theorem, but I don't quite understand how to begin to relate it to this question?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try looking at each interval $[x_i,x_i+1]$ separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a fixed partition $P = {x_0,\ldots,x_n}$, you want to prove that

$$\inf \{f'(t)\ : \ t \in [x_0,x_1] \} (x_1 - x_0) + \inf \{f'(t)\ : \ t \in [x_1,x_2] \} (x_2 - x_1) + \ldots \inf \{f'(t)\ : \ t \in [x_{n-1},x_n] \} (x_n - x_{n-1}) < f(b)-f(a)$$

But for each $i$, by the mean value theorem there is a $c \in (x_i,x_{i+1})$ such that
$f'(c) = \frac{f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_i)}{x_{i+1}-x_i}$

but then $$\inf \{f'(t)\ : \ t \in [x_{j},x_{j+1}] \} \leq f'(c) = \frac{f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_i)}{x_{i+1}-x_i}$$

And so $$L(P,f') = \sum_{i=1}^n  \inf \{f'(t)\ : \ t \in [x_{j},x_{j+1}] \} (x_{i+1}-x_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_{i+1}) - f{x_i}) = f(b)-f(a)$$